# Ajax call returning Array instead of value

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm trying to do an Ajax call, to show suggestions when a #hashtag is typed in a text box. For test purpose i'm trying to retrieve the $_POST[] data itself.

**home.php**

```
<textarea class="status" name="status" ></textarea>
<div class="hash-box">
<ul></ul>
</div>
```

**hashtag.js**

In here the `console.log(data)` outputs

> ```
> <li> <span class="getValue">Array</span></li>
> ```

Array is getting returned instead of the value.

```
    $(function(){
    var regex = /[#|@](\w+)$/ig;
    $('.status').keyup(function(){
        var content = $.trim($(this).val());
        var text = content.match(regex);

        if(text!=null){
            //var data = 'data='+text;
            $.ajax({
                url:'./hashtag.php',
                type:"POST",
                data:{datas:text},
                cache:false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
          }
       });
    });
```

**hashtag.php**

```
<?php

    echo '<li><span class="getValue">'.$_POST['datas'].'</span></li>';

?>
```

I tried `var_dump($_POST['datas'])` in `hashtag.php` and it works.

Comment: Never seen a function wrapped inside $() jquery stuff like that before. Also, indentation needs fixing

Comment: __Because__ `$_POST['datas']` is __array__.

Comment: what is the purpose of `/[#|@](\w+)$/ig` ?

Comment: @devpro to check if the input has # or @ followed by string or numbers,

Comment: @GeorgeAppleton - the $(function(){..... is just a shorthand for document ready - http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: `$_POST['datas']` is an array because you're sending an array in your ajax request, `match` returns an array.

Comment: I tried var_dump($_POST['datas']) in hashtag.php and it works. <--- what does, 'it works' mean?  What do you get for your output, a string, an array, an object?

Comment: @jameson2012 an array

Comment: exactly.  You can't echo out an array, you need to access the value inside the array, and then this will echo back to Ajax.  I suspect if you echo $_POST['datas'][0] you will get your desired result.  Then you may realise that @u_mulder was correct in both the duplication and his original answer

Comment: @jameson2012 that suggestion works.  Thanks bro.

Comment: no thanks required, but next time do some more thorough debugging, don't post vague statements like 'it works' and try to understand the advice people give you before you shoot it down.  And, for what it's worth, that answer isn't very good because who knows if you want element[0]?  You should either select the correct data and data type in your Ajax ( e.g. why are you sending back an array if you want a string?), or process the data in php with some checks to see if what you want exists and return an error or at least a default if it doesn't.   I hope that's helpful